# The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy” on shared webhosting server ASP.NET 4.0 with MS SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have created a web application in ASP.Net 4.0 framework and use MS-SQL for database interaction. I have build my code and upload on my shared web hosting server. Its home page working fine and all pages working fine where page content doesn't interact with database. But which pages interact database these pages gives me error :

```
Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.


Stack Trace: 

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +165
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +100
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +272
System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) +59
System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) +54
System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet) +33
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack securityContext) +154
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant) +54
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(PermissionType permission, PermissionSet targetGrant) +29
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +10540369
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility) +48
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner) +86
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDefaultConstructor(Type type) +68
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator(Type createdType) +37
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract) +257
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateArrayContract(Type objectType) +40
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType) +243
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type) +105
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +80
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +47
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +98
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters) +71
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName) +80
Ext.Net.XControl.get_SubmitConfig() +80
Ext.Net.ResourceManager.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +560
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6704
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
ASP.cms_files_images_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

How to resolve this error on shared server??

All code works fine on our local IIS server and our testing dedicated server but our client purchased a shared server and wants to run at shared server.

This issue is similar to thread posted on ["The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy" on shared webhosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242531/the-application-attempted-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-p)

but its solution is for LINQ with ASP.NET. I need solution to MSSQL with ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You may try by adding following code in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
</system.web>
```