# "The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy." Possible trust issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, cas

The full message is

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.

I've recently uploaded an MVC application to a Fasthosts hosted site.

The application runs fine locally in VS but not on the server.

It originally gave the message about enabling remote error messages so I added `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to the config file which initially stopped this.

I then saw the above error message, so after some Googling I added `<trust level="Full" />` to `<system.web>` but instead I get another message saying that the host has disabled this feature.

The thing is, there's nothing unusual about this application; it's just a very basic MVC app. It doesn't use resources on any other location than the current folder structure, so shouldn't really have any trust issues.

The problem is also exaggerated because there seems to be some kind of server-side caching issue.

The `<system.web>` section currently looks like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trust level="Medium" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
```

but it still says that I need to add `customErrors mode="Off"` to see error messages.

Adding various lines to the config file in various positions will eventually return it to the first error message, but not for any logical reason I can see.

For completeness, the controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int vehicleId = 0)
{
    ViewBag.VehicleId = vehicleId;
    return View();
}
```

The view is just a shedload of HTML with a few helper methods, one of which is as follows (the others are just different entities, same code otherwise):

```
public static MvcHtmlString Manufacturers(string id = "manufacturers", string className = "", string style = "", string optionClass = "", string optionStyle = "", int selectedValue = 0, bool showSelect = false)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DB())
        {
            var selected = selectedValue == 0 ? " selected" : "";
            result.Append($"<select id='{id}' class='{className}' style='{style}'>");
            if (showSelect) result.Append($"<option{selected} value='0' disabled='disabled'>(Select)</option>");
            foreach (var manufacturer in context.Manufacturers)
            {
                selected = manufacturer.ManufacturerId == selectedValue ? " selected" : "";
                result.Append($"<option{selected} value='{manufacturer.ManufacturerId}' class='{optionClass}' style='{optionStyle}'>{manufacturer.Name}</option>");
            }
            result.Append("</select>");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(result.ToString());
}
```

I have an open support ticket with Fasthosts but I'm not confident it'll be answered anytime soon :(

Comment: I dunno the answer to your question, but FYI, trust has more to do with what kinds of things the code can do than where it can be loaded from.  For instance, reflection is usually not allowed in a partial trust setting.

Comment: I think this MAY be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242531/the-application-attempted-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-p?rq=1 - am currently checking with Fasthosts...

Comment: Unfortunately Fasthosts support are next to useless. Will use a different hosting provider instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the host server, after they said it must be my code.

I found another provider, uploaded my code, all worked fine first time.

Sometimes it's not you, it's them.